# PHP Get months in specific quarter

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function in php that allows me to pass a quarter (1,2,3 or 4) to it and then have it return the month names in that quarter.

Example if Quarter was 1 :

```
function($quarter){

   //Based on the current quarter, the months returned are as follows:
   January, February, March

}
```

How could I achieve this with the output being an array of the 3 months in the quarter? The only 2 values that I will have to use with the function is the year and the quarter. (I have a drop down of years and 1-4 for the quarters. They will select one from each drop down and then I need the months within that quarter *I know the months will be the same regardless of the year*.

Comment: `if elseif else`? I think i may be missing something...

Comment: Finding out the months within a certain date range. I could figure out the start and end date of the quarter but dont know how to return each of the months in that period.

Comment: The months are always the same for each quarter. You don't mention a date range in your question...

Comment: grossly over thinking it... months in a quarter is not very dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not something as simple as:

```
function getMonths($quarter){
    switch($quarter) {
        case 1: return array('January', 'February', 'March');
        case 2: return array('April', 'May', 'June');
        case 3: return array('July', 'August', 'September');
        case 4: return array('October', 'November', 'December');
    }
}
```